# REGEX global 'i' not recognising the word 'He' with a capital letter and replacing it with 'She' but does recognise 'he'

Tags: javascript, regex

I would appreciate some guidance on where my error is.

At the moment, my code finds the word 'he' perfectly and replaces it with 'she'; however for some reason it ignores 'He' with a capital letter at the start of a sentence and replaces it with 'undefined'. I have included the global flag 'i' to ignore case sensitivity, but still, it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
var mapObj = {
      Childname : name,
      SchoolName : schoolName,
      he : 'she',
      his : 'her',
      him : 'her',
      himself : 'herself',
      she : 'he',
      her : 'his',
      herself : 'himself',
      boy : 'girl'
    };
```

Here is where the error likely is.

```
    for (var n = 0; n<data.length;n++) {
      let pattern = (gender === 'Male') ? new RegExp (/\b(Childname|SchoolName|she|her|herself|girl)\b/,'gi') : new RegExp(/\b(Childname|he|him|his|himself|boy)\b/,'gi')
      let changed = data[n][0].replace(pattern, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
          });
          changedComments.push([changed])
          }
          destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,changedComments.length,changedComments[0].length).setValues(changedComments)
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your regex [is fine](https://regex101.com/r/fCjfe6/1).

Comment: Because in your map you don't have "He". You need to convert to lowercase

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog, great, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beeing replaced with `undefined` because the match is `He` not `he` and you are returning `return mapObj[matched];` - so `return mapObj['He'];` - which is undefined.

`return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];` would work, but then your replaced text would start with a lowercase `she`. So you should also add a check if the first letter is uppeercase like [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascript#:%7E:text=Object%20Oriented%20Programming-,To%20test%20if%20a%20letter%20in%20a%20string%20is%20uppercase,case%20and%20see%20the%20result.) for example and then uppercase the first letter of your replacement like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript) if its required.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `matched` will be the substring that matches the pattern that you provide, so if your pattern is `/he/gi`, and the matched substring is `He`, then the returned substring match will still be `He`, which doesn't exist as a key in `matchObj`.

The simple way to fix this would be

```js
let changed = data[n][0].replace(pattern, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
});
```